# Visual Studio 2015 express missing amd64 option

Tags: visual-studio-2015, 64-bit, windows-10, visual-studio-express

I have a problem with Visual Studio 2015 Express that it seems to be missing files needed to setup the environment for a 64 bit compilation.

I have installed both Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2015 for Windows 10 and Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2015 for Windows Desktop. Now when I call the vcvarsall.bat with the option amd64 to setup the environment for a 64bit compilation I get the error message:

"The specified configuration type is missing.  The tools for the configuration might not be installed."

I check in my installations folder and I have vcvarsall.bat in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC but I'm missing vcvars64.bat in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64 which seems to be required. What am I missing?

Comment: You should install VS 2015 Community which has all the same features as VS 2015 Professional including the x64 toolset. Alternatively you can install the Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools 2015 if all you really want is the toolset (i.e. not the IDE).

Comment: I see, but as I understand it VS 2015 Community is not free? I tried also to install the build tools but it still does not provide the needed files.

Comment: VS 2015 Community is free if you meet the [license terms](https://www.visualstudio.com/support/legal/mt171547). If you don't meet them, just buy Professional. I would definitely expect to find the x64 toolset in the Build Tools SKU. I'll investigate that tomorrow. Do you have any other files in ``C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64``?

Comment: Still I thought that the express version would include these? In C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64 I only have the DLL vcmeta.dll

Comment: Express has always had a strange mix of features missing (graphics debugger is only in the "for Windows" version, no support for VSIX packages, minimal exceptions debugging support, no 64-bit toolset, etc.). Community is a much better option for individuals and open-source projects.

Comment: Ok. I had a closer look at the license terms and it seems that I'm eligible for the community version so I installed it and everything works now (the community version included the missing files). I leave the question open though until we get clarity and confirmation that it should or should not be included in the express version or if I did something wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio Express editions do not include the x64 toolset.

Comment: These days use the Community edition which does include the x64 toolset.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need the 64 bit compiler I recommend to install the [Visual C++ 2015 Build Tools](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools). However, you can't install it together with Visual Studio 2015 Express.

Comment: The build tools seem to have disappeared with the release of Visual Studio Community edition, but you can still find the old 2015 tools in the older downloads section: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/